# What does "swing through" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, meaning-in-context

> The Swedish Academy announced March 29th Bob Dylan will receive his Nobel Prize when he **swings through** Stockholm for two performances on April 1st and 2nd.

**swings through** here means **goes to** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **[swing through something](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/swing-through)** (Macmillan Dictionary)
>
> *to visit a place for a short time on your way to another place*

Comment: Please do not answer '[please-]google-this-for-me' questions on ELU.